# Как отличить одинаковые коды клавиш клавиатуры?

Tags: delphi, windows, клавиатура

Как отличить клавиши клавиатуры с одинаковым программным кодом? Например, "стрелку вверх" на стандартной клавиатуре и цифру 8 на цифровой клавиатуре справа ("тоже стрелочка вверх!"). Вот я обрабатываю код клавиши в хуке двумя способами:

**1 способ <структура PMsg>**

```
function KeyBoardProc(ACode: Integer; AWParam :WParam; AMsg: PMsg): LRESULT; stdcall;
begin
...
form1.caption:=Inttostr(AMsg.message);  // Структура PMsg
...
result:=CallNextHookEx(hh,ACode,AWParam,LongInt(Amsg));
end;
```

**2 способ <снятие(скан) состояния всех виртуальных клавиш>**

```
function KeyBoardProc(ACode: Integer; AWParam :WParam; AMsg: PMsg): LRESULT; stdcall;
var state:TKeyBoardState;
begin
GetKeyboardState(State);
for i:=1 to 255 do
if((State[i] and 128) <> 0) then form1.caption:=Inttostr(i);  // получаем нажатую
                                                              клавишу
result:=CallNextHookEx(hh,ACode,AWParam,LongInt(Amsg));
end;
```

Comment: И те и другие виноваты :-). И еще Рабинович :-)

Answer (score 4):

Посмотрите например [тут](http://blog.spreys.com/c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B) таблицу кодов клавиш.

Стрелка вверх:

Клавиша Десятичное
число Шестнадцатеричное
число Символическое
имя

```
курсор ↑    38  0×26    VK_UP
```

на нумпад

```
8   104     0×68    VK_NUMPAD8
```

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите также MSDN "KeyboardProc callback function"

Кратко: нужно проверять на "расширенность клавиши", это 24-й бит в параметре lParam, у вас он почему-то назван AMsg.